# Extracting regularization path from glmnet

Tags: r, glmnet, elastic-net

Does glmnet provide any mechanisms to extract the regularization path from a final model? I'm using Elastic Nets (and L1) to build a binomial classifier and would like to be able to get the coefficients at each step along the path (until convergence).

The `elasticnet` R package has this in the `beta` variable of the model, but it looks like `glmnet` only provides the final coefficients for each model. Any suggestions for how to go about pulling this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glmnet` provides a full coefficient path. Try the following example out for yourself:

```
# code partially scavenged from the glmnet docs because I'm lazy
library(glmnet)

set.seed(123)

#binomial
x=matrix(rnorm(100*20),100,20)
g2=sample(1:2,100,replace=TRUE)
fit2=glmnet(x,g2,family="binomial")

plot(fit2) # plot coefficient paths

summary(fit2) # NB: 63 lambda values tested

dim(fit2$beta) # 20 by 63, as we'd expect
```

The number of lambdas tested is contingent on the random seed and properties in the data. To illustrate this, change the above example such that you are starting with `set.seed(111)` and you'll end up with 55 lambdas tested instead of 63. It's possible that lasso is converging extremely quickly for you and glmnet isn't even bothering to give you more than one lambda. I doubt that's the case, but it's probably possible.

If you are specifying `lambda` in your call to `glmnet`, then you won't get a coefficient path since the path is only meaningful over varying lambdas. If this doesn't answer your question, try to provide a minimal working example of your code.

Comment: Ahh of course, you are exactly right. I was trying to find something like in `elasticnet` where the path could be plotted by iteration, but this makes sense in the case of logistic regression. Thank you!